# Prometheus scraping error "expected timestamp or new record, got "MNAME"

Tags: prometheus

I have attached the Prometheus with my metrics rest endpoint but I am receiving the error "expected timestamp or new record, got "MNAME". My endpoint produces the response body which looks

```
ElapsedScanTime_count {Subject="DEV-Product-1"} 0.563 
LiveActivities_count {Subject="DEV-Product-1"} 53 
LogEvents_count {Subject="DEV-Product-1"} 0 
LogEventsProcessed_count {Subject="DEV-Product-1"} 56717
```

I am ending each line like below

```
string prometheusFormat = "";

foreach (var metric in metricsArray.Values)
   {
   prometheusFormat += metric .ToString () + " " + Environment.NewLine;
   }
```

Comment: can you try removing the space between the metric and the labels?

Comment: and also make sure you end your lines with a line feed character (`\n`). I think `Environment.NewLine`  is environment specific. Prometheus require `\n`

Comment: also, you shouldn't be camel casing your metrics. Check [metric and label naming](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/),

Comment: can you confirm the string "like below" in your endpoint payload is a typo?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Yes, it was a typo in the body, I removed it. Furthermore, I have tried to with the changes you mentioned but still, I am facing the same issue. Now my payload looks like 

liveactivitiesbeingtracked_count{Subject="DEV-CompCenter-signal-384"} 0 \nlogeventsreturned_count{Subject="DEV-CompCenter-signal-384"} 40 \nlogeventsscanned_count{Subject="DEV-CompCenter-signal-384"} 492 \n

Comment: can you update your code? are those \n literal strings or real new line characters?

Comment: Not a C# expert, but should be "\n"

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be easier to instrument your code with [prometheus library](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net)? It even includes a metric server that exposes the instrumented metrics.

Comment: \n works. Thanks for you help!!

Comment: Cool! The response I've posted below addresses the issue. Please accept it and have a nice prometheus time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example should comply with Prometheus API format:

```
$ echo 'elapsed_scantime_count{Subject="DEV-Product-1"} 0.563' | ./promtool check metrics
elapsed_scantime_count no help text
```

Remove camel case, remove whitespace and end each line with a `\n`

Also, don't use hyphens or periods in metric names, numbers at the start of label or metric names.

Make sure metrics comply with the regex `[a-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z0-9_:]*` and labels must comply with the regex `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`

Prometheus metric and label naming best practices: [Link](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/)

Prometheus data model (metric and label name): [Link](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels)